# After deploy to production error: Unknown provider: $$isDocumentHiddenProvider <- $$isDocumentHidden

Tags: angularjs

After deploy angularjs stopped working on server(production and staging).
Error: `[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$isDocumentHiddenProvider <- $$isDocumentHidden <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- $compile <- $$animateQueue`.

I do not understand what went wrong, to the last deploy it worked well, now after even rollback an error display. 
This is an example of my controller:

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
// ...
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
```

Please, help me.

My bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
     //......
    "angular": "1.5.6",
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.6",      
    "angular-material": "^1.1.1",
    "angular-aria": "^1.5.8"
  }
```

UPD.

The caret, on the other hand, is more relaxed. It will update you to the most recent major version (the first number). ^1.2.3 will match any 1.x.x release including 1.3.0, but will hold off on 2.0.0. i'm remove caret in animate and aria. Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem.

I was using angular-material (installed with bower) but i didn't fixed the versions i was using.

i work with angular 1.5.9 but when bower ulpoaded angular-material 1.1.1, angular-animate and angular-aria where in 1.6.0 version

I added these lines in my bower.json file and now it works :

```
"angular-animate": "1.5.9",
"angular-aria": "1.5.9",
```

Comment: I have laid my bower.json, please see it.

Comment: Thank you very much helped me

Comment: The caret, on the other hand, is more relaxed. It will update you to the most recent major version (the first number). ^1.2.3 will match any 1.x.x release including 1.3.0, but will hold off on 2.0.0.
i'm remove caret in animate and aria. Thanks

Comment: This happened to me when we moved the code to a new server, the errors were so cryptic but they matched the one in this question and this totally solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You saved the day!